# Opencv image translation artifacts (C++)

Tags: c++, image, opencv, translation, homography

I have created a stitching algorithm that can stitch many images together. It doesn't use a bundle adjustment but that is a later addition to be made.

After finding the homography between the two images I am stitching I do a series of translations, perspectiveTransforms and warpPerspectives to achieve my end result. The following two images are two image stitched the first being images passed left to right and the latter being images passed right to left. Each image includes information about the translation matrix created to stitch the images. The result image is the new padded size of a blank images that will contain the stitched images (what you are seeing pictured). [image]

```
Image 1: Min x 478.711 Min y 3.16 Max x 1853.66 Max y 1449.42
Image 2: Min x 0 Min y 0 Max x 1200 Max y 900
Result Image: Min x 0 Min y 0 Max x 1853.66 Max y 1449.42
[1, 0, 0;
 0, 1, 0;                                                                       Stitch 2
 0, 0, 1]
```

[image]

```
Image 1: Min x -671.462 Min y -461.816 Max x 652.656 Max y 655.324
Image 2: Min x 0 Min y 0 Max x 1200 Max y 900
Result Image: Min x -671.462 Min y -461.816 Max x 1200 Max y 900
[1, 0, 672;
 0, 1, 462;                                                                     Stitch2/Rev
 0, 0, 1]
```

Looks like it works great which is awesome. However when I run the code piping in 3 images I get weird lines where the black background should be and then my padding begins to fail. Again reference images and translations.

[image]

```
---------------------
Image 1: Min x 390.279 Min y 72.4343 Max x 1658.93 Max y 1110.17
Image 2: Min x 0 Min y 0 Max x 1200 Max y 900
Result Image: Min x 0 Min y 0 Max x 1658.93 Max y 1110.17
[1, 0, 0;
 0, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 1]

Image 1: Min x 439.817 Min y -20.4711 Max x 2205.2 Max y 1288.93
Image 2: Min x 0 Min y 0 Max x 1200 Max y 900
Result Image: Min x 0 Min y -20.4711 Max x 2205.2 Max y 1288.93
[1, 0, 0;
 0, 1, 21;
 0, 0, 1]
---------------------
```

Code for this section follows. Any help is appreciated.

```
Mat result, descriptors_updated;
    vector<Point2f> fourPointImage1, fourPointImage2, image1dst, image2dst;
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_updated;
    float min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y, result_x, result_y, img1_min_x, img1_min_y, img2_min_x, img2_min_y,img1_max_x, img1_max_y, img2_max_x, img2_max_y, result_min_x, result_max_x, result_min_y, result_max_y;

    //get four corners of image MATs
    fourPointImage1 = fourCorners(image1);
    fourPointImage2 = fourCorners(image2);

    //get the min and max corners
    tie(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y) = minMaxCorners(fourPointImage1);

    //- Htr use to map image one to result in line with the already warped image two
    Mat Htr = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64F);
    if (min_x < 0){
        max_x = image2.size().width - min_x;
        Htr.at<double>(0,2)= -min_x;
    }
    if (min_y < 0){
        max_y = image2.size().height - min_y;
        Htr.at<double>(1,2)= -min_y;
    }

    //- Need to create a padded blank image to accomodate stitched images.
    //- Must first determine where the translations of the two images will end up to determine if shift is needed and how much to pad blank image
    perspectiveTransform(fourPointImage1, image1dst, Htr*homography);
    perspectiveTransform(fourPointImage2, image2dst, Htr);

    //- Now determine what is out of bounds
    //New coordinates for image 1
    tie(img1_min_x, img1_min_y,img1_max_x,img1_max_y) = minMaxCorners(image1dst);
    cout << "Image 1: Min x " << img1_min_x << " Min y " << img1_min_y << " Max x " << img1_max_x << " Max y " << img1_max_y << endl;

    //New coordinates for iamge 2
    tie(img2_min_x, img2_min_y,img2_max_x,img2_max_y) = minMaxCorners(image2dst);
    cout << "Image 2: Min x " << img2_min_x << " Min y " << img2_min_y << " Max x " << img2_max_x << " Max y " << img2_max_y << endl;

    //determine bounding area for resulting images
    result_min_x = min(img1_min_x, img2_min_x);
    result_max_x = max(img1_max_x, img2_max_x);
    result_min_y = min(img1_min_y, img2_min_y);
    result_max_y = max(img1_max_y, img2_max_y);

    cout << "Result Image: Min x " << result_min_x << " Min y " << result_min_y << " Max x " << result_max_x << " Max y " << result_max_y << endl;

    //Determine size of padded result (blank image) to be used for stitching
    result_x = (abs(floor(result_min_x)) + abs(ceil(result_max_x)));
    result_y = (abs(floor(result_min_y)) + abs(ceil(result_max_y)));

    result = Mat(Size(result_x,result_y), CV_32FC1,Scalar(0,0,0));

    //-Move the images to the postiive by creating a matrix to represent the translation
    int anchor_x, anchor_y = 0;
    Mat translation = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64F);
    if(result_min_x < 0){
        anchor_x = (int) floor(result_min_x);
        translation.at<double>(0,2) -= anchor_x;
    }
    if(result_min_y < 0){
        anchor_y = (int) floor(result_min_y);
        translation.at<double>(1,2) -= anchor_y;
    }

    cout << translation << endl;

    //Warp each image accordingly to the new padded result image
    warpPerspective(image2, result, translation, result.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_TRANSPARENT,   0);
    warpPerspective(image1, result, (translation*homography), result.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_TRANSPARENT,0);

vector<Point2f> fourCorners(Mat image){
    vector<Point2f> corners;
    corners.push_back(Point2f (0,0));
    corners.push_back(Point2f (image.size().width,0));
    corners.push_back(Point2f (0, image.size().height));
    corners.push_back(Point2f (image.size().width, image.size().height));
    return(corners);
}

tuple<float, float, float, float> minMaxCorners(vector<Point2f> imageMatrix){
    float min_x1, min_x2, min_y1, min_y2, max_x1, max_x2, max_y1, max_y2,img_min_x, img_min_y, img_max_x, img_max_y;
    min_x1 = min(imageMatrix.at(0).x, imageMatrix.at(1).x);
    min_x2 = min(imageMatrix.at(2).x, imageMatrix.at(3).x);
    min_y1 = min(imageMatrix.at(0).y, imageMatrix.at(1).y);
    min_y2 = min(imageMatrix.at(2).y, imageMatrix.at(3).y);
    max_x1 = max(imageMatrix.at(0).x, imageMatrix.at(1).x);
    max_x2 = max(imageMatrix.at(2).x, imageMatrix.at(3).x);
    max_y1 = max(imageMatrix.at(0).y, imageMatrix.at(1).y);
    max_y2 = max(imageMatrix.at(2).y, imageMatrix.at(3).y);
    img_min_x = min(min_x1, min_x2);
    img_min_y = min(min_y1, min_y2);
    img_max_x = max(max_x1, max_x2);
    img_max_y = max(max_y1, max_y2);
    return{img_min_x,img_min_y, img_max_x, img_max_y };
}
```

**EDIT** I am not sure but it only happens sometimes as you can see in the following image.

[image]

Comment: Just random guess, may be random memory content of the target buffer, where the final big image is rendered. As the 2-stitch works for you, it may a bit more tricky, like accidentally adding/removing alpha channel from intermediate images, making the RGB random data visible. From your question I have zero idea how you actually do the transformation and which bitmap routines are used, so I may be completely wrong about the cause.

Comment: @Ped7g thanks for the suggestion I will look into it. I used to be able to stitch multiple images together just fine the issue was the images were order dependent. When I added an extra section to allow for random order the issue began to show up. I can add the code if you think you might be able to decipher the issue.

Comment: I don't use opencv enough often to even recall what you may be using, so it's very likely your source will not tell me anything. Still providing some sort of [MCVE] may allow some other opencv users to just try to compile it and run at their place, which may greatly improve your chances to receive answer, without working binary it's difficult to "debug" the source just from question text. The ordered vs random sounds even more weird, maybe with ordered you create new target buffers every time in some more robust way? With random order reusing some, or skipping some init step?

Comment: Where are the images combined into one? The source looks incomplete, the interesting part I would try to experiment with first is: `warpPerspective(image2,  ...)` ... both warps have `BORDER_TRANSPARENT`. What if the first image used to create the big one for composition would receive warp argument `BORDER_CONSTANT` with black solid colour? The remaining 2nd, 3th, etc... images may probably retain `BORDER_TRANSPARENT` (but I'm not sure, maybe constant transparent color (full alpha) would work even better).

Comment: @Ped7g they are combined at the warpPerspective you mention. The stuff before hand is determining translations needed and how big the "result" blank Mat should be as that is what the images a warped too. I will play around with what you said though it is an interesting idea.